# Iterating over matrixes in a list stopped in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numpy, matrix

I would like to iterate over a matrix of matrixes (indeed, sounds weird),

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array

A = ar([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]], [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [[20,21,22],[23,24,25],[26,27,28]]])

B = np.copy(A)
C = np.copy(A)

im = np.array([A,B,C])
```

in order to receive the matrix which stores the values of (x,y) position in subsequent matrixes. For example, in [1, 2, 3], on the postion of 1, that means: A[0,0,0], there will appear only ones in the next matrixes. Thus I will receive an array in the new matrix (considering also A[0,0,1] and A[0,0,2]):

```
[[1  1  1] [2  2  2] [3  3  3]]
```

Therefore for the first array of A:

```
[[[1  1  1] [2  2  2] [3  3  3]]
[[4  4  4] [5  5  5] [6  6  6]]
[[7  7  7] [8  8  8] [9  9  9]]]
```

I have created this function:

```
def loop_ar(arr):
    matrix, v, c, s = arr.shape
    new = np.zeros((v,c,s,matrix)) #The columns in the last array of new represent the subsequent arrays
    for x in range(v):
        for y in range(c):
            for s in range(s):
                for ma in range(matrix):
                    new[x,y,s,ma] = arr[ma, x, y, s]
    return new
```

However, the output indicates, that the matrix stops iterating after few turns:

```
[[[[1. 1. 1.]
   [2. 2. 2.]
   [3. 3. 3.]]

  [[4. 4. 4.]
   [5. 5. 5.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

  [[7. 7. 7.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]]


 [[[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

  [[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]

  [[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0.]]]

   ...
```

When I tested this function on the list of lists, it worked. What has happened in this case? How can I fix it? It os only a simple case to illustrate my expectations; however, I would like to know the solution to a more complex problem, when B and C are not the copies of A. How can I force then the loop to iterate?

The B and C in the more complex case should have the same shape as A, howeb=ver they will differ in the last array. As in A we have:

```
[1  2  3]
```

in B we would have for example on the same position:

```
[23  34  56]
```

and in C:

```
[54  43  32]
```

Therefore the new matrix will include the array:

```
[[1  23  54]  [2  34  43]  [3  56  32]]
```

I have completed this task (I hope so) with converting a list to an array, because loop_arr worked for lists. However, it is a roundabaout. I want the solution and the explanation of the interruption in looping.

Here I present random data for the more complex question:

```
A = ar([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],[[20,21,22],[23,24,25],[26,27,28]]])

B = ar([[[23,34,56], [56, 78, 90], [12, 34, 32]], [[74,75,65], [25,57,76], [90,24,35]]])

C = ar([[[13,31,53], [54,96,69], [78, 90, 99]], [[35,64,66], [13,35,53], [37,73,61]], [[62, 87,97], [80,35,62], [75,76,67]]]
```

The new matrix would look like:

```
[[[[1  23  13]  [2  34  31]  [3  56  53]]
[[4  56  54]  [5  78  96] [6  90  69]]
[[7  12  78]  [8  34  90]  [9  32  99]]]
      ...so on, so on, so on...
                                     ]]]]
```

Comment: Where is `a` coming from?

Comment: User:  Sorry, in the end I decided that capitalized letter would be more highlitghted, but seemingly I have omitted few "as". @Onyambu, I will try this. However, could you explain your answer?

Comment: you are looking for `np.kron(a,np.ones(3)).reshape(np.r_[a.shape,3])` In this case, you are doing a `kronecker` multiplication which is literally repeating the matrix

Comment: Thank you, I have checked the docs. I have to admit it is only a simple case and kron doesn't suit my expectations for more a complex problem. Matrixes B, C don't have to be the copies of A. How can I then include their values or force the loop to iterate?

Comment: @fgh what exactly do you want to achieve? This is just for matrix a, you can do a kronecker product of any two matrices, You can as well do a matrix multiplication or rather binding to obtain what you need

Comment: How do you want your `b` or `c` to look like?

Comment: Your solution is indeed a  v e r y   good solution to this simple case. Indeed, I have to add further explanation t the post, which I have submitted.

Comment: A minute, I will edit the main post.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what the for loop does or rather what you are trying to create.

Comment: where is your B? How do you get 23? I mean you have not created a B. Even with your for-loop you cannot get a 23 when there is no 23 . you need to say what B is then we change the B to what you need.

Comment: That `for s in range(s):` iteration level is causing the incomplete iteration.

Answer (score 1):

numpy is already vectorized. You can do a kronecker product:

```
 np.kron(a,np.ones(3)).reshape(np.r_[a.shape,3])

array([[[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 3.,  3.,  3.]],

        [[ 4.,  4.,  4.],
         [ 5.,  5.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  6.,  6.]],

        [[ 7.,  7.,  7.],
         [ 8.,  8.,  8.],
         [ 9.,  9.,  9.]]],


       [[[11., 11., 11.],
         [12., 12., 12.],
         [13., 13., 13.]],


        : : : : 
        : : : :
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [44]: A = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]], 
    ...: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], [[20,21,22],[23,24,25],[26,27,28]]]) 
    ...:                                                                         
In [45]: A.shape                                                                     
Out[45]: (4, 3, 3)
In [46]: im = np.array([A,A+10,A+20])                                                
In [47]: im.shape                                                                    
Out[47]: (3, 4, 3, 3)
```

Looks to me like your code just transposes the axes, putting `matrix` dimension last instead of first.  `np.stack` takes an axis parameter.  Alternatively we can use the `transpose` function/method:

```
In [48]: im1 = np.stack([A,A+10,A+20], axis=3)                                       
In [49]: im1.shape                                                                   
Out[49]: (4, 3, 3, 3)
In [50]: im2 = im.transpose(1,2,3,0)                                                 
In [51]: im2.shape                                                                   
Out[51]: (4, 3, 3, 3)
In [52]: im2                                                                         
Out[52]: 
array([[[[ 1, 11, 21],
         [ 2, 12, 22],
         [ 3, 13, 23]],

        [[ 4, 14, 24],
         [ 5, 15, 25],
         [ 6, 16, 26]],

        [[ 7, 17, 27],
         [ 8, 18, 28],
         [ 9, 19, 29]]],

        ....
        [[26, 36, 46],
         [27, 37, 47],
         [28, 38, 48]]]])
In [53]: np.allclose(im1,im2)                                                        
Out[53]: True
```

I can't test you more complex case because `B` has the wrong shape.  And `C` has the wrong terminating character.

===

To see what's wrong with your iteration, print `s` at the start of its loop.  Look at how it evolves.  Then change the iteration variable to `k`, and watch that.

Comment: That's great! Changing s solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: The problem was with s, I have omitted the s - this is my typical changing element in for loops, like x or y. I didn't mean specific calculations, I fouced rather on the indexes, positions.